# HTML Audio - How go to next track when the active ended with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm creating an audio player with HTML audio and jQuery.
My markup:

```
<ol class="playlist">
  <li>
    UNICALEGRIA
    <audio class="track" preload="none">
      <source src="<?php echo $siteroot; ?>/audio/joao/docevapor/unicalegria.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
  </li>
  <li>
    ausência
    <audio class="track" preload="none">
      <source src="<?php echo $siteroot; ?>/audio/joao/docevapor/ausencia.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
  </li>
  <li>
    TIPUMORGASMO
    <audio class="track" preload="none">
      <source src="<?php echo $siteroot; ?>/audio/joao/docevapor/tipumorgasmo.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
  </li>
</ol>
```

And my script:

```
$(function() {

  if($('.playlist')) {

    $('.playlist').find('li').prepend('<button class="control play">&#9654;</button>');

    $('.playlist').on('click', ".play", function() {

      var track = $(this).siblings('.track');

      $('.playlist .track').trigger('pause');
      $('.playlist .play').removeClass('active');

      $(this).addClass('active');
      track.trigger('load').trigger('play');

    });
  }
});
```

I want that when the actual playing music ends the next one on the playlist starts automatically, but I could not find anywhere a method or function to do that. Can someone here help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ended` event:

```
$('<current audio element here>').on('ended', function() {
    // start next track
});
```

(or use a common handler and check `event.target.*` to identify).